# jQuery click run animation then click again

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a small piece of code that when `.nav-trigger` is clicked the `.home-page` will animate to the left and when `.nav-trigger` is clicked again the `.home-page` will return to 0.

Problem is, when I click the `.nav-trigger` it immediately runs `click 2` which is not what I want.

```
$('.nav-trigger').click(function(){
    $('.home-page').animate({
        left: '-260px'
    });
    console.log('click 1');
}, function() {
    $('.home-page').animate({
        left: '0px'
    });
    console.log('click 2');
});
```

I have tried changing from `click(function()` to `hover(function()` and the `hover` works but I need `click` to work

Comment: you need to use .animate callbacks

Comment: The `click` handler doesn't work like this. The reason hover works is because the first parameter passed in is the code to be executed for "mouseover" and the second parameter is "mouseout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create your own toggle functionality, you can do that using a flag and the data() method, something like this :

```
$('.nav-trigger').on('click', function(){
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    $('.home-page').animate({left: flag ? -260 : 0});

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgLx6/)

Comment: Not sure if OP is interested but putting in `.stop()` could prove useful from the UX experience standpoint

Comment: True, a `stop(true, true)` would avoid some issues if someone clicks the button multiple times, but that's really up to the OP.

Comment: @adeneo thanks! I had to put `$('.nav-trigger').data('flag', true);` before the `.on('click,function()` but this code is great!

Comment: @DonaldSutherland - Ah, that means the order is wrong, you can just swap the -260 and 0 numbers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to my comment in your question, try this:

```
// track the clicks
var click = 0

$('.nav-trigger').click(function(){
    // increment the counter
    click++;

    // odd clicks go left -260px
    if(click%2==1){
        $('.home-page').stop().animate({
            left: '-260px'
        });
    }
    else{
        // even clicks go back to 0px
        $('.home-page').stop().animate({
            left: '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/souviiik/QYV6b/

```
$('.nav-trigger').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $('.home-page').animate({
           "margin-left": 0
        });
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        console.log('click 1');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('.home-page').animate({
           "margin-left": '-260px'
        });
        console.log('click 1');
    }
});
```